# i was making tic tac toe and got confuse how can i give "x","0"value to all the rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box bt-0 bl-0"><span class="text"></span></div>
    <div class="box bt-0">     <span class="text"></span></div>
    <div class="box bt-0 br-0"><span class="text"></span></div>
    <div class="box bl-0">     <span class="text"></span></div>
    <div class="box">          <span class="text"></span></div>
    <div class="box br-0">     <span class="text"></span></div>
    <div class="box bl-0 bb-0"><span class="text"></span></div>
    <div class="box bb-0">     <span class="text"></span></div>
    <div class="box br-0 bb-0"><span class="text"></span></div>
  </div>
```

I was making tic tac toe and got confuse how can I give "x","0"value to all the rows and columns

This is the js that i have applied

```
let allboxes=document.querySelectorAll(".box")

for (i=0;i<allboxes.length;i++)


allboxes[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{

    $("div.text").click(function(){
        $(this).closet()
    })
})
```

Comment: I made something like this before, although the approach is a bit different
https://github.com/njtan142/TicTacToe

Comment: `$(this).closet()` .... closest what? and what do you want to do with the closest? note `div.text` ... yet none of your div's have that style ... the spans do though ... it's all so confusing - also, you forgot the jquery tag since you're using it

Comment: There are several issues with your code. For starters, `for (i=0;i<allboxes.length;i++)` is missing an opening `{`. Secondly you have spelled the `.closest()` method incorrectly, but it is still unclear what you want to achieve. By value, are you referring to a string that is displayed on the div? Please specify.

Comment: i wanted to give innertext   (i.e x,0) when someone click?      {what i did}=      firstly i applied click function to all the box classes... (for that)  i  initialize variable allboxes to target all box classes.  secondly i performed loop to select all boxes so that when someone clicks on any box it work accordingly.  Then i was trying to give innertext to the clicked boxes but  didn't understand what to do